# Unset created variables or objects before returning in php

Tags: php

In terms of `Memory Optimization`, if there are too many requests to server, is there any difference between these two scripts:

```
public function func1(){
    $user = new User::find(10);
    $name = $user->name;
    return $name;
}


public function func2(){
    $user = new User::find(10);
    $name = $user->name;
    unset($user);
    return $name;
}
```

if yes, could you please explain why.

AND, won't PHP itself unset variables while exiting a function or method ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I am quite positive there isn't any difference, since once the function is done running and the value has returned, the variables inside the function are "removed" from the memory automatically.

Comment: PHP should remove from the memory once is used, but it's good practice unset manually at least for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer to [questions-about-php-unset-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234732/questions-about-php-unset-function) and the article [better-understanding-phps-garbage-collection](http://www.sitepoint.com/better-understanding-phps-garbage-collection/) indicate that garbage collection occurs when the function returns, so memory used by the local variables is automatically freed on return. Therefore explicitly calling unset just prior to return does not appear to provide a memory optimization.